# How many columns am I supposed to have in this situation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

This is a general question on dealing with a models fields and just wanted to know if this is the correct way to go. Let's say I have the model `House` and the users can select a choice of 10 features it has:

```
Swimming Pool
Hot Tub
Tennis Court
Boat Parking
Horse Facilities
Balcony
Pets Allowed
Energy Efficient
Lease Option
Disability Features
```

This means I have to make 10 boolean columns right? I never worked with so many table columns so I'm not sure. Is it normal practice to have so many?

Thank you.

Comment: It's not alarming for a table to have 200 columns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another option would be to have a table called HouseOptions (or whatever you like) and then a join table called something like UserHouseOptions.

The AR relations would look like:

```
# user.rb
has_many :user_house_options
has_many :house_options, :through => :user_house_options

# user_house_options.rb
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :house_options

# house_options.rb
has_many :user_house_options
has_many :users, :through => :user_house_options
```

User, then, has no extra columns. It just has that join table through AR relationships. User House Options would have two columns: user_id, and house_options_is. And then House Options has just the string column ("Swimming Pool", etc), and it's just a reference table.

Check out this Rails guide for more information about has_many :through relationships (and example code):
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association

Comment: Yes do it this way.  By having a separate model managing the house features you will be fine when you add that house down the road with a helipad.  You just need to add Helipad in the app rather than mess around adding new columns to the house model.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not alarmed by the number of fields, but you might want to generalize your design, so you could easily implement new features.

He's one idea for a design.

```
> rails generate Model Feature type:string house_id:integer

class House < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :features
end

class Feature < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :house
end

class SwimmingPool < Feature
  def to_s
    "Swimming Pool"
  end
end

house = House.create
house.features << SwimmingPool.new
house.save!

house.features.each do |feature|
  puts feature
end
```

Answer (score 2):

This may be feasible but implementing code could be messy.
One possible solution is to serialize

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :preferences
end

user = User.create(:preferences => { "background" => "black", "display" => large })
User.find(user.id).preferences # => { "background" => "black", "display" => large }
```

Here we use preferences which is just a hash but you can also use arrays

Another solution, create a table for each feature and use joins but thats could be even messier ha. I'll update my answer as i ponder this more

Answer (score 2):

My other answer (using polymorphic classes) is just an idea.  Another more plain way is to have a feature_types table, where you list Swimming Pool in the name field, and a many-to-many linking table.  See has_many :through.

This table solution is easily extendable to add another type.

The polymorphic class solution is extendable *if* you want to extend class specific behavior.  For instance, swimming pools might include data like "olympic size" in the to_s base on quality data in the features table.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the use you can create a field of array for e.g. known as features and you can insert the type of features the house has in that array.